# arcobjects determine when attribute dialog window closed

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, features, fields-attributes, vb.net

In arcmap, I choose to "Display the attributes dialog before storing new features" in editor options for several layers.

I intend to do further development upon user closing the attribute dialog window (for new created feature).

So I want to check how to determine when the attribute dialog window (see the picture below) is closed.

[image]

I am using arcmap and arcobjects 10.2.2, vb.net arcmap add-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to listen for attribute window events. Seems you can access them from this interface: [iAttributeWindowEvents](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IAttributeWindowEvents_Interface/00200000004s000000/)

There is an 'onDeactivate' event that you'll want to listen for to trigger your next section of code.

There should be plenty of code samples around showing how to listen for events in ArcObjects.net.